# Shortest path of a rectangular cuboid in a board

Tags: breadth-first-search, shortest-path, dijkstra, a-star

I have a challenge with shortest path algorithms. I have a rectangular cuboid in a board (screenshot attached), the movement of the cube is done doing a rotation on one of the edges. So depending on the state the cube can occupy 2 tiles in the board, or standing in one tile of the board. On every rotation the size (in tiles) of the next movement could change. Is there any algorithm capable of calculating shortest path with this behavior? Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Looks like Bloxorz. I don't see why BFS or A* wouldn't work. See [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/338759312_Game_of_Bloxorz_Solving_Agent_Using_Informed_and_Uninformed_Search_Strategies), which I haven't read, but looks promising.

Comment: @ggorlen that paper is exactly what I've been looking for. And I've found a kata with a similar problem https://www.codewars.com/kata/5a2a597a8882f392020005e5/train/kotlin 
Thanks! If you post the answer I will mark it as selected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done using BFS. In the Queue we need to maintain a tuple "state of cuboid" + "Current Cells of Cuboid" and need to figure out immediate next cells the cuboid can move to and in in which state and Push that in the Queue. It's a standard Breadth First Search Question.

Comment: _"In the Queue we need to maintain a tuple "state of cuboid" + "Current Cells of Cuboid"_  the current cells could be part of the Cuboid state.